# GitHub - Basic MultiBranch design?

Tags: git, github, development-environment

How should I design the branches and the pipeline for a basic project on GitHub?

I've seen several designs, but I'm not sure which one fits my project...it's confusing,

Current project:

- 3 Developers and only one WebServer

So I made the following branches:

- Dev1
- Dev2
- Dev3
- PreProd
- Production (Which will be connected to the Web Server)

Pipeline:
Each developer push changes to the branch assigned (Dev1, Dev2, Dev3)
Next Step:

- Merge from DevX to PreProd
- Merge from PreProd to Production

Every time a developer wants to send a change, should they first clone the PreProd branch on their local machine? ... or the Production branch?... How can I make sure they have reliable data?

Comment: Do all branches were created on the remote git server?

Comment: No, just the Production branch in the WebServer, the rest on each developer's local machine.

Comment: Just my opinion - Branches should be associated with tasks, not people. Let the developers create their own branches as needed and push them to the remote. Pull requests are based on merging these branches with PreProd. Destroy the branches when pull requests are completed. Developers fetch PreProd (or possibly Prod) to update their local environment, then create a new branch for a new task. Merging PreProd to Production should be the job of one person (or automated task given a set of criteria; tests successful, etc).

Comment: @J.Titus So based on your answer, If my assumption is correct then, the developers should first fetch PreProd before making changes in their local machines (so they will have the lastest project version)...and working in that clone, each developer should make changes/commit/push the feature to an X branch in GitHub, which must be immediately eliminated once it has been approved and merged to PreProd in GitHub...? ...Did I understand well?

Comment: @Tana Precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can share one scenario with you. Usually for any project there exists three branches called:

- Production (Connected with live server)
- QA/Staging (For testing purpose)
- Development (Development main branch)

Ideal scenario is your developers will create their own feature branches say feature-1, feature-2 etc. and create a pull request into the Development branch after finishing their features.

After that, if all features for next release exist in the Development branch, Development branch will send a pull request into the QA/Staging branch. After testing, if all tests passes, then the changes will be merged into Production branch. So the cycle look like:

Features -> Development -> QA/Staging -> Production